# Insert into Data.Set and check if element exists at the same time

Tags: haskell

Is there an efficient way to insert a value into a [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html) while at the same time checking if that value was already a member of the set?

If there isn't, is there any particular reason such a function would be impossible to write with the current implementation of sets in the `containers` library?

Comment: Are you wanting to insert an element if and only if it's not already in the set, but not repeat the work of traversing the structure to insert it if it's not?

Comment: @bheklilr Yes, that's another way of saying it. All I want to do is `(Set.member elem set, Set.insert elem set)`, just more efficiently (not repeating work). For example, in C++, you can compare the return value of `insert` to `.end()` to check whether the element was already a member of the set, without requiring a separate call to check for membership.

Comment: So you're wanting a function `insertIfMissing :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> (Set a, Bool)` that indicates if the inserted value was actually inserted?

Comment: @bheklilr yes, exactly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `O(log n)` complexity by taking advantage of the fact that `size` is `O(1)`, and just compare before and after:

```
-- | Inserts a value into the Set.  If the value was not already in the set,
-- | then True is returned, otherwise False
insertIfMissing :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> (Set a, Bool)
insertIfMissing a s = (newSet, missing)
    where
        newSet = Set.insert a s
        oldSize = Set.size s
        newSize = Set.size newSet
        missing = oldSize < newSize
```

And if you aren't interested in whether it was already present, then this shouldn't compute the `missing` part thanks to laziness.

Comment: Oh, that is a nice trick! Just a minor note: I think the complexity of `(Set.insert elem set, Set.member elem set)` is also `O (log n)`, so the complexity argument is not relevant here, it's only about the constant factors.

Comment: @bennofs The complexity is the same, but it'll repeat work.  You're basically ending up with the difference between `O(log n) + O(1) + O(1)` and `O(log n) + O(log n)`.  Using `Set.member` will probably be noticeably slower for large sets.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to write such a function by slightly changing the `Set.insert` function. I decided to return a `Maybe (Set a)`, so the function only creates a new `Set` if the element did not alredy exist. It would be equally well possible to write a function with `(Bool, Set a)` as return type.

```
insertMember :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Maybe (Set a)
insertMember = go
  where
    go :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Maybe (Set a)
    STRICT_1_OF_2(go)
    go x Tip = Just $ singleton x
    go x (Bin sz y l r) = case compare x y of
        LT -> do 
           l' <- go x l
           return $ balanceL y l' r
        GT -> do 
           r' <- go x r
           return $ balanceR y l 
        EQ -> Nothing
```